# Can ansible create a dict using the common values from a list and a dict?

Tags: ansible, vmware, vcenter

In ansible, the vmware_guest_info module will give us a list of the tags on a vm, but does not include any information about those tags:

> "tags": [
>      "10.16.3",
>      "dicky",
>      "develop"
>   ],

The vmware_tag_info module gives us a dict withinfo on those tags, including description and Id, but NOT the tags name:

> "10.16.3": {
>      "tag_category_id": "urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceCategory:6eb9d643-8fa3-42a1-8b50-78a1c6e99867:GLOBAL",
>      "tag_description": "10.16.3",
>      "tag_id": "urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceTag:ca46ab80-be91-4c3a-8f9f-019d163dd954:GLOBAL",
>      "tag_used_by": []
>   },

The vmware_category_info module gives us a list that includes ID and name of a tag.

> "tag_category_info": [
>    {
>      "category_associable_types": [],
>      "category_cardinality": "SINGLE",
>      "category_description": "nodeVersion",
>      "category_id": "urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceCategory:6eb9d643-8fa3-42a1-8b50-78a1c6e99867:GLOBAL",
>      "category_name": "nodeVersion",
>      "category_used_by": []
>   },
>   ]

So it seems I need to combine the output of three different lists to get the tag value, tag name and tag ID.

I really hope that someone has already done this.  If not, can anyone shed some light on how to iterate over the output of vmware_tag_info and vmware_category_info, and find when tag_category_id matches category_id?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```yaml
---
- name: Example playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    vcenter_hostname: change me
    vcenter_username: administrator@vsphere.local
    vcenter_password: change me
    dc1: change me
    vm_name: change me
  tasks:
    - name: Gather tags information
      vmware_tag_info:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: no
      register: tags_info_result

    - name: Gather tags category information
      vmware_category_info:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: no
      register: tags_category_info_result

    - name: Set tags_information variable
      set_fact:
        tags_information: >-
          {{ tags_information | default({})
            | combine({
                item.key: tags_category_info_result.tag_category_info
                | selectattr('category_id', '==', item.value.tag_category_id)
                | list
                | first
                | combine(item.value)
                | combine({'tag_name': item.key})
                })
          }}
      with_dict: "{{ tags_info_result.tag_facts }}"

    - name: Gather VM information
      vmware_guest_info:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: no
        datacenter: "{{ dc1 }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
        tags: true
      register: vm_info_result

    - name: Display VM tags information
      debug:
        msg:
          - "tags information about {{ vm_name }}"
          - "{{ tags_information[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ vm_info_result.instance.tags }}"
      when:
        - "'tags' in vm_info_result.instance"
```

Comment: The "Gather VM information" task failed with the message: "**Information gathering failed with exception Expected VapiStruct instance or python dictionary, but received str**"  

I'm running:  
`ansible 2.10.1  
python 3.8.5  
pyvmomi 7.0  
vSphere-Automation-SDK 1.32.0`

Comment: The error was a known bug.  
The bug is already fixed, so can you try the following fixed module again?

https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.vmware/pull/406